# PHP, regex, and capitalization

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to capitalize what my regex captures/matches. Say I wanted to capitalize the first character after a hyphen, my regex would be something like this:

`-(.)`

And my replacement string would be something like this:

`-\U1`

In `preg_replace`, I would have something like this:

`$string = preg_replace('/-(.)/', '-\1', $string);`

But this doesn't work in `preg_replace` (and I don't think it supports changing the case in a backreference). Suggestions?

Comment: You can do it with `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: to reinforce @Barmar's comment "5.5.0  The /e modifier is deprecated. Use preg_replace_callback() instead.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
  $string = preg_replace_callback(
           '#(?<=-)(.)#',
           create_function(
               '$matches',
               'return strtoupper($matches[1]);'
           ),
           $string
       );
```

Or, with an anonymous function (using PHP ver >= 5.3.0):

```
$string = preg_replace_callback( '#(?<=-)(.)#', function( $matches) {
    return strtoupper( $matches[1]);
}, $string);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/IpoCvB

Comment: @nickb: Thanks for the edit, though it would be proper to mention that anonymous functions became available after PHP 5.3.0 only.

Comment: Yeah, but 5.3 has been out since June 2009, so for almost 4 years. If your host doesn't support 5.3 by now, it's time to get a better host.

Answer (score 0):

`$string = preg_replace('/(?<=-)(.)/e', 'strtoupper("$1")', $string);`

The [e modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: `The e modifier has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.5.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`